# QTP, How to verify that the Accept button is relative to that user?

Tags: automation, qtp

I Have an issue with QTP, my task is to verify that request is been sent from a specific user and to accept that request to that person.

can any of you help me of how to verify that request is sent and to click on "accept request" button for specified user.

refer to the below snapshot. if i want to verify the sent request from "Cross31" user and 
to click on "Accept Request" button for that user.

your help is highly appreciated.

thanks 
Manaysah[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.

#### VRI

Probably the simplest one is using Visual Relation Identifiers, in order to do this you should learn the user you're interested in *cross31* and the button you want, then open the object repository go to the button's properties and a relation to *cross31*.
[image: VRI]

#### XPath

Assuming this is a web application you can enter an XPath into the description of the button that defines it's relative position to the *cross31* element (assuming you know enough XPath)

#### Object hierarchy

Even though QTP usually ignores uninteresting parents you can manually add the common ancestor of the button and the person (assuming it's unique) and drag the button beneath this object.

Comment: Thanks alot Motti, that was extremely helpful, 
about the fist solution, using VRI, its not the best solution as it may fail in some cases as the accept button does not exist always. 
and for object hierarchy i had tried it before but its not working 
i think the best solution will be the xpath.